# fancybox open relative div

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I'm trying to figure out how to open a div in fancybox relatively from the link that was clicked.

```
<div class="tool">              
    <ul>            
        <li><span class="more-info"><a href="#" title="View more info">?</a></span>         
            <div class="help">This is the help text</div>           
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I know I can add something like `#uniqueDiv` to `a` and then a div with id `uniqueDiv`, however I would prefer that when the link is clicked, it opens the closest div with class `help`.

I tried something like this with no luck:

```
$('.more-info a').click(function(e){
    $(this).parent().next().fancybox();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

-Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about this problem for a few more hours and decided to approach it differently, since I was pretty much at a dead end. I was thinking that if I can't target a relative div, maybe I can then auto-assign the `href` and `id` values, so each link can then be targeted via its id.

This actually worked out beautifully and meets all my requirements:

```
$('.more-info a').each(function(index){
    var x = index + 1;
    $(this).attr('href', '#box' + x);
    var li = $(this).parent().parent();
    $('.help', li).attr('id', 'box' + x);
}).fancybox();
```

1. `$('.more-info a').each(function(index){` I target all my links and loop through them.
2. `var x = index + 1;` The index starts at 0, but for readability, I start it at 1.
3. `$(this).attr('href', '#box' + x);` I take the current link's `href` value (currently `#`) and replace it with `#box[INDEX]` where index is a unique, auto-incrementing number.
4. `var li = $(this).parent().parent();` I move back a view elements so I can hone in on my hidden div `.help`.
5. `$('.help', li).attr('id', 'box' + x);` I now target the `.help` div and add an attribute called `id` and set it to `box[INDEX]`. I now have the necessary association between link and hidden div so that fancybox can do its magic.
6. `}).fancybox();` This lets fancybox know to open my links with it.

jQuery functions used:
[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/), [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr), [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent)

Any suggestions or improvements are still appreciated.

-Ryan